# How to use require in cloud functions

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud-functions

I'm trying to execute a code node.js in IBM Cloud Functions, but I have an require that isn't pre-installed. Its the
const {google} = require('googleapis')
How can I install?

Comment: Looking at this article here, it looks like this guy uses `Webpack` to build his app before he uploads to IBM cloud: https://medium.com/@yunyuenchan/how-to-use-npm-module-in-ibm-cloud-functions-a0c76154e85

Answer (score 0):

Package the action as a zip file and include a `node_modules` directory with external dependencies (`googleapis`) needed.

Official documentation has more details about this approach: https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/docs/actions-node.md#packaging-an-action-as-a-nodejs-module